# Istanbul code coverage : how to ignore such lines?

Tags: node.js, code-coverage, istanbul

when performing code coverage , all my .catch() statements are uncovered, is there a way to specify /* istanbul ignore next */ somewhere
 ?

ex :

```
 function list(req, res, next) {
  const { limit = 50, skip = 0 } = req.query;
  User.list({ limit, skip })
    .then(users => res.json(users))
    .catch(e => next(e)); <= this line is marked as uncovered
  }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yep it is, just change `.catch(e => next(e));` to

```
.catch(
/* istanbul ignore next */
(e) => { 
  next(e);
});
```

Comment: current docs: https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#parsing-hints-ignoring-lines